# Android event.getY() returns different value in api 10 and api 16

Tags: android, gridview, motionevent

Currently I'm trying to develop an app, where on the one half of the screen (the upper half) is a picture and in the other half (the bottom half) is a grid view. 
When I now click on one of that tiles of the grid view, I try to get the relativ y-Coordinate of this click with event.getY(). On Android 2.3.3 I get 88 - correct for me, I have to use this value later for some calculations. But on Android 4.0 it gives me a value about 576 what seems to me as if it was the absolute coordinate of that touch event...

Can anyone explain this difference between these two versions? And is there a solution for getting the relative value also in Android 4.0?

Answer (score 0):

How are you testing this? My 4.2 always gives me the co-ordinate with respect to the view...

I think it is likely due to the two devices having different resolutions. As the 2.3.3 is likely older, it most likely has a lower resolution screen. Try testing on two identical virtual devices (the only difference being the version of android). You can also try testing on two 2.3.3 devices with wildly different resolutions.

As practice, I always try to normalize the co-ordinates before I use them (i.e. `event.getY()/view.getHeight()` ). This way you don't have to worry about resolution.

EDIT:

If you absolutely cannot get the relative coordinates (I don't know why this is the case, but anyway...), you can play the game and always acquire the raw coordinates and do the relative calculations yourself. i.e. use `getRawX()` / `getRawY()` , and subtract the coordinates of the top-left corner of the view, which you acquired from `View.getLocationOnScreen()` and/or `getLocationInWindow()`. Not as efficient, but a useful work-around.

Comment: Hey dberm, thanks for your answer :) I tested this with my galaxy s+ (2.3.3) and a google nexus phone (4.0). As you suggested I also tested my program in the emulator with two devices with different screen size at 2.3.3 - values are correct.  The test with two identical screen sizes(480x800) on different android versions(2.3.3 & 4.0) is also correct. But test on an device with android 4.0 and screen size of 720x1280 gives me again the absolute value?! Dont understand this...very confusing... :((

Comment: So the test on 2.3 & 4.0 (each having the same screen size and resolution) showed the same value? This makes me think it is not an issue with the api version, and the program is acting as it should. But then you say that the larger screen size gives you a different value? Is it roughly 1.5x your original value (showing that you are not accounting for resolution), or is it something completely different? Have you tried it with the higher resolution on 2.3.3?

Comment: Yeah, I tried it with a higher resolution on 2.3.3 - gives me the correct value...I dont understand this behaviour. Hm no its not the 1.5x of the original value, on 4.0 at small resolution I get a value about 95 and at 4.0 at a higher resolution I get 650...seems as if it is the absolute value instead of relative. -.-

Comment: Ahh, that's absurd. There seems to be no rhyme or reason for that. Well, maybe you can use the workaround in my edit since we can't find the root of the problem.